# Sending notification from Splunk to external application

Tags: splunk

Is it possible to send notifications from Splunk to external application?

The user scenario is that Splunk is used and set up already so the business applications are monitored properly. We have an application (let's call it ACME) that needs to receive alerts from Splunk (e.g. if *OutOfMemoryException* occurs in the log file of the business application then an alert has to be sent to the ACME application).
My question is how Splunk can notify (send the alert to) the ACME application that the error occured? Can Splunk call a REST service? Or via JMX?

Thank for the help!
Regards,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. After [creating the alert](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.0/Alert/AlertTriggerConditions) for the *OutOfMemoryException*, you can create a [Webhook](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.3.0/Alert/Webhooks) alert action that can POST to "ACME" REST API. Triggering [scripts](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/7.2.6/Alert/Runscriptaction) are also an option.